# Use of ' in offset

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I have some code, can someone explain how it works and why it works that way? Specifically this line of code:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Now I get it that the code itself outputs the date in `Cells(1,1)` and offsets by `1` from the bottom for every subsequent entry. What I don't understand is why in the sheet itself one of the cells is blocked out?

[image: This is what I mean by blocked out, cell A2 is filled with '--------]

And then the code works fine. But if cell `A2` doesn't have `'--------` it suddenly doesn't work anymore and gives me `Application defined, object defined` error. Can someone explain what `'--------` does here and why its used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the code is: "Jump to the last row that is used in column A, go down 1 row and write the date into it.

What it does:
Go (virtually) to cell A1 and press (also virtually) the key Ctrl+Down. This jumps to the last used cell of a column - but only if there is more than one cell filled, else it will jump to the *very last* row of the sheet (try this in Excel to understand).

Now if you offset one row from the very last row of a sheet, Excel cannot do anything more than complain.

The solution: Use `.Cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)` instead. This works the opposite way: Go to the very last row and press Ctrl+Up. For more details how to find the last used cell, see
[Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

What you also should do:
Don't cascade things, use intermediate variables, that helps debugging.
Don't write a date as string (`format` converts a date into a string). Write the date as date and set the number format of the cell.

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lastCell as Range
    Set lastCell = .Cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
    lastCell.Offset(1).Value = Date
    ' If needed:
    ' lastCell.Offset(1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

When there is no value in `A2`, it will give you an error because `End(xlDown)` from `A1` will take you to the last cell `A65536` in Excel `2003` and `A1048576` in Excel `2007+`. It is like selecting cell `A1` and manually pressing the `End` key and then the `Down` arrow key. And of course you can't offset **down** from the last cell and hence you are getting the `Error 1004 - Application-defined or Object-defined error`.

[image]

I recommend using `xlUp` to find the last row and then enter the data as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Here is an example

```
Dim lRow As Long

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End With
```